# how to effectively resolve PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large in React Native Frontend?

Tags: json, react-native, expo

So I have stored 800kb JSON data from API into async storage, but when I try to loop over that data I receive

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at readStream (C:\Users\Vartotojas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:155:17)
    at getRawBody (C:\Users\Vartotojas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:108:12)
    at read (C:\Users\Vartotojas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:77:3)
    at jsonParser (C:\Users\Vartotojas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:135:5)
    at call (C:\Users\Vartotojas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\connect\index.js:239:7)
```

I don't want to use any database or backend though it seems not too large dataset. Since async storage can store 6mg, why did I receive this error in the first place? And shouldn't it just be truncated instead? Or it's just a warning for console.log and if so how to resolve it?

Comment: `AsyncStorage.clear(); ` helped though I was writing data on top of the old one.